# Can I add a comment to an ajax call that's visible in fiddler when I look at what gets sent out?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have code like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/xx"
        }).done(onAjaxDone).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Dialog.Alerts.ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
```

and

```
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/xxxxx"
        }).done(onAjaxDone).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Dialog.Alerts.ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
```

When I check with fiddler I notice more than one ajax call. Is there some way I can add some meta to the ajax calls that would not be used but that would allow me to see where the call is coming from in my code. Something like a comment that I could place within the ajax() and that would be visible going across the network?

Comment: You mean like `url: "/xxxxx?debuggingComment=FromFunctionOne"`?

Answer (score 2):

You could send some meta-data in a non-standard header, using the `headers` option:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    headers: { MyCustomHeader: "Location #1" }
});
```

Then check for it on the server side using `Request.Headers["MyCustomHeader"]`.

You could also append a key to the query string, but I suppose using an HTTP header is less invasive.